# pbuilder-dist fails if cmake can't find non-mandatary c++ feature support?

Tags: deb, cmake, bazaar, pbuilder, pbuilder-dist

I'm trying to submit a deb to my PPA according to this manual:
https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html
I'm able to build my app with `bzr builddeb -- -nc -us -uc` and to sign it with `bzr builddeb -S`. But execution of `pbuilder-dist groovy build myproject_0.2.8-1.dsc` in `../build-area` fails.
Full log is available in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/whr6Qsd1

I believe that the problem is in following piece:

```
Determining if the CXX compiler accepts the flag -fno-keep-inline-dllexport failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /build/myapp-0.2.8/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake cmTC_3ab02/fast && gmake[1]: Entering directory '/build/myapp-0.2.8/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3ab02.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3ab02.dir/build
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/build/myapp-0.2.8/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3ab02.dir/DummyCXXFile.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++0x -fno-keep-inline-dllexport   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3ab02.dir/DummyCXXFile.cxx.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/DummyCXXFile.cxx
c++: error: command-line option '-fno-keep-inline-dllexport' is not supported by this configuration
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_3ab02.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_3ab02.dir/DummyCXXFile.cxx.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/build/myapp-0.2.8/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake[1]: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_3ab02/fast] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/build/myapp-0.2.8/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'



dh_auto_configure: error: cd obj-x86_64-linux-gnu && cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR=/etc -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCALSTATEDIR=/var -DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON -DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RUNSTATEDIR=/run -DCMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY=ON "-GUnix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu .. returned exit code 1
make: *** [debian/rules:6: binary] Error 25
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
```

So, `cmake` is checking that `/usr/c++` supports `-fno-keep-inline-dllexport`. Compiller ends with 1 bcs it doesn't support it, cmake returns 2 and dh_auto_configure painics.

If I execute `cmake` on my system I'm getting following stdout:

```
-- Checking to see if CXX compiler accepts flag -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections
-- Checking to see if CXX compiler accepts flag -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections - yes
-- Checking to see if CXX compiler accepts flag -fno-keep-inline-dllexport
-- Checking to see if CXX compiler accepts flag -fno-keep-inline-dllexport - no
-- Checking to see if CXX compiler accepts flag -Werror=return-type
-- Checking to see if CXX compiler accepts flag -Werror=return-type - yes
```

So even compiller on my system doesn't support `-fno-keep-inline-dllexport`. And I'm fine with that. It doesn't matter for me. `cmake` not fails.

It looks that the failed check of non-mandatory feature by `cmake` ruins whole `pbuilder-dist` process. Are there any way to change this behaviour or i'm missing something?

P.s. My build-depends are: `debhelper-compat (= 13), cmake (>=2.8.9), gcc (>=4.6), qt5-qmake (>= 5.4), qtbase5-dev (>= 5.4), libtiff5-dev (>= 4.0.3), libjpeg8-dev (>= 8c), libpng-dev (>=1.6.2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not certain about the exact issue prompted by you configuration.
But two possible solutions are

1. Changing `-std=c++0x` to `-std=c++11`.
2. Remove option `-fno-keep-inline-dllexport`.

Please check your configuration files, where to modify this.

Prior to this, you can check if any of these options would work.
Go to the parent directory of `CMakeFiles` and try replicating the failed command at the command line, with the suggested modifications:

1. `/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11 -fno-keep-inline-dllexport   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3ab02.dir/DummyCXXFile.cxx.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/DummyCXXFile.cxx`
2. `/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++0x -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3ab02.dir/DummyCXXFile.cxx.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/DummyCXXFile.cxx`

For this to work, you would likely need to call first `cmake --debug-trycompile` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115842/how-to-keep-generated-temporary-files)).

**Notes** about your pastebin (messages worth noting, even though not necessarily problems) and procedure:

1. You have tons of `ln: failed to create hard link '...' => '...': Invalid cross-device link` messages.
2. There is a problem reported with `Qt5LinguistTools`. Perhaps it is worth [installing `qttools5-dev`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51698075/cmake-cannot-find-qt5linguisttools-in-docker-ubuntu-18-04) prior to what you did.
3. It reports `Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!`. It is worth checking what are possible sources of problems.
4. It helps a lot if you specify the exact list of commands you issued, including the directory where each command was issued.
5. What do you mean by "If I execute `cmake` on my system..."? Same as point above.

**Related**:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523412/qt-config-c11-but-std-c0x

https://code-examples.net/en/q/129e754

Comment: 1. doesn't help. 2. works. Indeed I found the code in one of subfolders that sets default GCC flags using `CHECK_CXX_ACCEPTS_FLAG()`. This module is deprecated, but updating `TestCXXAcceptsFlag` to `CheckCXXCompilerFlag` and `CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG()` changed nothing. So I just excluded a check for `-fno-keep-inline-dllexport` support. Still I believe this is a bug, but seems not to be a `pbuilder-dist` problem. It's a `dh_auto_configure` problem.

Comment: Btw, I managed to google out an alternative but bad solution [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=117944&start=30). They suppressed compiler error by passing `-g` option. If one make a `/tmp/1.cxx` with single line `int main() { return 0; }` he'll be able to reproduce the error with `/usr/bin/c++ -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -o 1.o -c 1.cxx`. But specifying `-g` option suppresses it. Looks like compiler just ignores -f optimization and don't parse params. But that's obviously bad workaround as it leads to false positive compiler capabilities detection.

Comment: @truf - Intriguing, at best...
PS: It's good to have feedback.